# Get or Put objects on Amazon S3 with pre-signed URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm very new to AWS, and I'm trying to allow users to access / upload some pictures on S3 with pre-signed URLs.

Here is my code:

```js
const getLinkForKey = key => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {Bucket: PICTURES_BUCKET, Key: key};
    S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => err && reject(err) || resolve(url));
});
```

I'm getting an URL from that, but when I try to access the link I've received, I get an access denied exception.

I think I maybe need to configure some bucket policy or something like that, but I'm really confused on this subject.

Do you know how to make this work?

Thanks,

Comment: In bucket permissions, allow `Everyone` to be able to list/view the files.

Comment: If I do so, everybody will be able to access thoses pictures, won't they? I'd like to give a specific link to specific people for them to access a specific picture

Comment: If you know their IPs, you can create a policy.

Comment: This is entirely dynamic, so no IP and no manual config, I want to generate a link on ask, as it should be possible with the getSignedUrl method

Comment: you can create expiry token with AWS

Comment: How? Isn't it exactly what the getSignedUrl is supposed to do? I'd like to make it work with that method if possible

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the pre-signed URL should be working for you. Just to provide a quick explanation...

**By default, all objects in Amazon S3 are private.** You can then add permissions so that people can access your objects. This can be done via:

- Access Control List permissions on individual objects
- A Bucket Policy (that grants wide-ranging access based on path, IP address, referrer, etc)
- IAM Users and Groups (that grant permissions to Users with AWS credentials)
- Pre-Signed URLs

A **[Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)** can be used to grant access to S3 objects as a way of "overriding" access controls. A normally private object can be accessed via a URL by **appending an expiry time** and signature. This is a great way to serve private content without requiring a web server.

If your goal is to serve content only where a Pre-Signed URL is used, then:

- Do not assign any permissions via the normal methods listed above (this keeps them private by default)
- Use **Pre-Signed URLs** to access objects

**Your code is:**

```
const getLinkForKey = key => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {Bucket: PICTURES_BUCKET, Key: key};
    S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => err && reject(err) || resolve(url));
});
```

I notice that you are **not passing the `Expires` parameter**, which specifies the validity period of the pre-signed URL. Here is a code sample from the [Amazon S3 documentation for node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property):

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Expires: 60};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log('The URL is', url); // expires in 60 seconds
```

Therefore, it is quite possible that **the link expired before you tested the URL**. I recommend you provide an `Expires` parameter and set it to a length suitable for your intended use (eg 300 seconds).

Comment: On the documentation, it is said that by default, the Expires is set for 15 minutes. I've still tried to set it manually and the result is the same, Access Denied :-/

Comment: Check that you don't have another policy that overrides the security (although I'm not sure that would apply with pre-signed URLs). For example: Bucket policy should probably be empty, IAM permissions for the signing user should not have a DENY. You could also test the creation of pre-signed URLs via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [`aws s3 presign` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html).

Comment: is it possible the we can generate those presigned URLs from the console

Comment: @MuhammadYounas Please create a new Question rather than asking questions within comments of old topics. (And, no, you can't create presigned URLs from the console. The closest is using [aws s3 presign](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html).)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out where the issue was. I was executing my code into a lambda that had not proper access to S3 configured. Unfortunately, there was no error to help me find this. It is now fixed, and the links work :)

Comment: You answer made it work for me as well -- as was in the same scenario, trying to presign an URL from inside a Lambda without permission. Thanks a lot.